# What is Harry’s latest broom?

Tags: harry-potter, flying-brooms

After the destruction of his Nimbus 2000, Harry received a Firebolt as a Christmas present.

Is the Firebolt the last broom he received, or did he get a newer broom during the course of the books?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**The Firebolt is the last broom he received during the series, although it seems to be lost by the end.**

In *The Battle of the Seven Potters* (chapter 4 of *Deathly Hallows*), Harry’s broom falls from Hagrid’s bike as they’re attacked by Death Eaters:

> Screams, a blaze of green light on every side: Hagrid gave a yell and the motorbike rolled over. Harry lost any sense of where they were: Streetlights above him, yells around him, he was clinging to the sidecar for dear life. Hedwig’s cage, the Firebolt, and his rucksack slipped from beneath his knees—
>
> “No — HEDWIG!”
>
> **The broomstick spun to earth,** but he just managed to seize the strap of his rucksack and the top of the cage as the motorbike swung the right way up again.

They never go back to retrieve the broom, and the Firebolt is never mentioned again. Harry never owns another broomstick during the final book (unless you count the one he uses in the Room of Requirement).

However, given that Ginny goes on to play Quidditch professionally, I’m sure Harry would buy a replacement broom eventually (and probably use it to play/practice with the kids).

Comment: How expensive was a firebolt? Are we talking about the cost of a new computer from Best Buy? An Alienware? A Jetta? A porche? Any idea what the cost of one would be?

Comment: @JFA: The shop window in Diagon Alley says “Price upon request”, which means ~expensive. But Harry has both the Potter and the Black fortunes, plus substantial celebrity, so I think he could afford a decent broom.

Comment: Yea, they mention that. Are we talking about a Ferrari then?

Comment: @JFA: Honestly no idea, price wise, but a high-end supercar does seem roughly comparable.

Comment: Now that I think about it, it would make sense if it was even the price of a Jetta or an expensive motorcycle. No one would be able to justify the most expensive broom when a regular one could do the trick. Someone has to ask Rowling.

Comment: 2000 galleons sounds familiar.

Comment: "No one would be able to justify the most expensive broom when a regular one could do the trick." The entire luxury industry defies this statement.

Comment: Accio would surely work, if it did during the trials and the broom was in the magically protected castle, then it should work elsewhere.

Comment: @self.: When Harry summoned the broom, he had a pretty good idea of where it already was. In this case, he doesn’t, and the broom may be destroyed beyond repair. Plus, a broom flying cross-country may attract unwanted attention.

Comment: @alexwlchan You don't need to know where the object is to successfully cast the spell. I don't remember any reference from the books that would support your statement. Also this source disagrees with you: http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_spells

Comment: @self. You’re right about the summoning charm; my mistake. But the secrecy issue remains. (Also, HP Wiki isn’t generally treated as a reliable source here.)

Comment: @alexwlchan There is not "secrecy issue". Molly weasley successfully casted accio on the twins when they were hiding their joke products, even though she didn't know that the products were there, what exactly the products were and exactly where they were( pockets, bags...). Do you have any reference to support your claim?

Comment: @self. I meant the issue of Harry’s broom flying across the skies when he tried to summon it later. (I doubt he’d be summoning it during the flight.) It would be a clear breach of the Statute of Secrecy, and give the Ministry a reason to arrest him.

Comment: @alexwlchan That is not an an issue I was contesting. The accio spell would work.

Comment: @self. It might work, but the secrecy issue makes it unusable. But let’s leave it there; this isn’t going anywhere useful.

Comment: @alexwlchan That is right, your point which is something I never argued about is going nowhere.